# an error occured while starting the kernal (Spyder)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

An error ocurred while starting the kernel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 27, in 
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 23, in 
from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from .application import *
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 19, in 
from traitlets.config.configurable import Configurable, SingletonConfigurable
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 12, in 
from .loader import Config, LazyConfigValue, _is_section_key
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 16, in 
from ipython_genutils.path import filefind
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipython_genutils\path.py", line 13, in 
import random
File "C:\Users\Al madina\random.py", line 1, in 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 134, in 
import tempfile
File "C:\Users\Al madina\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in 
from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random' from 'random' (C:\Users\Al madina\random.py)
```

Comment: Please provide some information about your environment.

Comment: Additionally, please format / rewrite your question in a way that asks a question and provides some background into that you've tried.  We are at a disadvantage as we do not have the same contextual knowledge as you.  Thanks!

Comment: Please remove or rename this file: `C:\Users\Al madina\random.py`